# iOS 7 Class size compatibility

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I've read Apple Documentation about Class sizes and their backward compatibility.

It says, that most classes are compatible with iOS 7 and the main restriction is Compact Height value for iPhone.

Has anyone managed to separate iPhone landscape orientation from portrait? It works great for separating iPads from iPhones, but I didn't get any results for iPhone.

I tried:
Portrait: wCompact - hRegular
Landscape(default): Any - Any

It always uses Portrait version for both orientations.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to get CGRect:

.h file

```
@interface FullScreen : UIScreen
+ (CGRect)iOS7StyleScreenBounds;
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "FullScreen.h"

@implementation FullScreen
+ (CGRect)iOS7StyleScreenBounds {
UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen]; CGRect screenRect;
if (![screen respondsToSelector:@selector(fixedCoordinateSpace)] && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
    screenRect = CGRectMake(screen.bounds.origin.x, screen.bounds.origin.y, screen.bounds.size.height, screen.bounds.size.width);
} else {
    screenRect = screen.bounds;
}
return screenRect;
}
@end
```

and call this class like:
[FullScreen iOS7StyleScreenBounds]; in your .m file

Comment: I'm not quit sure how this can help. I'm trying to avoid setting constraints in code.